# how to find the nearest parent or children by coordinates?

Tags: postgresql, parent-child, postgis, geojson

I try to find via postgis the nearest parent of a polygon in order to have a parent -> children hierarchy. 
How do I do my SQL query(s)?

example of data : https://gist.github.com/flug/6d356b50e68545930ddd123153b02d52

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Could you add some sample data? Also add a create table statement.

Comment: I added other data, the problem is that if I try to add them via the browser and the editor, it breaks the browser :-/

Comment: @Flug consider sharing just some test data (a small portion of the original data set)

Comment: @JimJones, I agree, Flug, edit your questions and share a small portion of your test data that will match the criteria you need, we can't go through that wall of text in the link you provided.